# new tab in bash on Arch Linux starts at home directory

Tags: gnome-terminal, cwd

On my Arch box, when I hit Ctrl+Alt+T `bash` opens a new tab in the Terminal's window. The `pwd` of this new tab is the current user's home directory. On my Ubuntu box at work however, the `pwd` of the new tab is the same `pwd` of the old tab.

How can I tell `bash` on my Arch box to behave like `bash` on my Ubuntu box?
Is it even a `bash` thing, or does Ubuntu include a customized variant of `bash`?

Comment: I don't think that has anything to do with bash, no. It's a terminal setting. What terminal are you using? Is it gnome-terminal?

Comment: Check out this question - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/144896/open-new-terminal-tab-in-current-working-directory-doesnt-work you might find an answer there

Comment: I am using Gnome-Terminal 3.20

Comment: Make sure `/etc/profile.d/vte-2.91.sh` is sourced by your shell at startup. This should be done by your distro. If not, a quick workaround is to add `source /etc/profile.d/vte-2.91.sh` to your `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: That did the trick. What does this script do. I am not that into shell programming to get it.

Answer (score -1):

on archlinux, I added this to .bashrc file in user's home directory

```
source /etc/profile.d/vte.sh
```